# Set permission to users during databricks notebook runtime

Tags: azure-databricks, acl, user-permissions

There is a notebook in databricks, certain business people dont have right to view the job runs. Only admins and one more group have access to view them. In the permissions section , I can set it manually so that some users
to manage runs so they can see the job logs. But this is a manual work every time the notebook runs and i want to automate this task. How can i proceed ?
I am using this script currently, but the response is 403

```
import requests
import json

# Databricks workspace URL
url = "https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/admin/users/create"

# Databricks API token
token = "<your-api-token>"

# Headers for the API request
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Function to add user to Databricks workspace
def add_user(username, email, display_name):
    payload = {
        "user_name": username,
        "email": email,
        "display_name": display_name,
        "password": "password"  # Change to the desired initial password
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"User '{username}' added successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to add user '{username}'. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # List of users to add
    users_to_add = [
        {"username": "user1", "email": "user1@example.com", "display_name": "User One"},
        {"username": "user2", "email": "user2@example.com", "display_name": "User Two"}
        # Add more users as needed
    ]
    
    for user in users_to_add:
        add_user(user["username"], user["email"], user["display_name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following endpoint to create a new user:
[**/api/2.0/accounts/{account_id}/scim/v2/Users**](https://docs.databricks.com/api/account/accountusers/create#account_id)

The request sample should look like this:

```json
{
  "id": "string",
  "userName": "user@example.com",
  "emails": [
    {
      "$ref": "string",
      "value": "string",
      "display": "string",
      "primary": true,
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "givenName": "string",
    "familyName": "string"
  },
  "displayName": "string",
  "roles": [
    {
      "$ref": "string",
      "value": "string",
      "display": "string",
      "primary": true,
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "externalId": "string",
  "active": true
}
```

Make changes to your endpoint and `payload`.
To obtain the `account_id`, follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/).

Error 403 is related to authentication, so provide the correct [token](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/pat.html#databricks-personal-access-tokens-for-workspace-users). However, you will still encounter an error with your current endpoint, so change it as mentioned above.